# How to use dynamic data to create area chart using dc.js and crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am creating dynamic data to use in Area chart. The chart should look similar to this: [image: Area chart required]

Below is the data which needs to use:

```
let transformedSubscriptionData = [
  {
     active: 2
     canceled: 22
     date: Sun Jun 09 2019 16:59:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
     month: "6"
     skip: 10
  },
  {
     active: 10
     canceled: 2
     date: Sun Jun 09 2019 16:59:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
     month: "6"
     skip: 0
  }
]
```

There are 3 status in data active,cancelled and skip but, these status are not fixed there could be more status added to data for example a status called subscribe or any other could be added so this should be handle dynamically.

I have achieved the above problem and the last data will be transformedSubscriptionData.

**The problem**

As the status are dynamic the chart should render the data dynamically.

**Code Explanation**

Below is the dimesion created from data:

```
let subscriptionFacts = crossfilter(transformedSubscriptionData);
let allSubscription = subscriptionFacts.groupAll();
let subscriptionDateDimension = subscriptionFacts.dimension(function(d){ 
return d3.timeMonth(d.date)});
```

Below the status are filtered and stored in object form then pushed to the array as they are dynamic:

The subscriptionStatusArray below contains status like ['active','cancelled','skip']

```
 let subscriptionSumArray = [];

 subscriptionStatusArray.forEach(status => {
   let obj = {};
   obj[status] = subscriptionDateDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d[status]})

   subscriptionSumArray.push(obj);
 });

 var minDate = d3.timeMonth(subscriptionDateDimension.bottom(1)[0].date);
 var maxDate = d3.timeMonth(subscriptionDateDimension.top(1)[0].date);
```

The subscriptionSumArray contains filtered data like this: [image: subscriptionSumArray]

The above data is then added with chart below:

```
 let subscriptionChart = dc.lineChart(".subscription-chart")
         .width(400)
         .height(400)
         .brushOn(false)
         .margins({top:10,bottom:30,right:10,left:70})
         .dimension(subscriptionDateDimension)
         subscriptionSumArray.forEach((curr , index) => {
             for(let key in curr) {
                if(index === 0) {
                    subscriptionChart.group(curr[key], key)
                } else {
                    subscriptionChart.stack(curr[key], key)
                }
             }
         })
         subscriptionChart.title(function(d) { return d.key.getDate()+ ' '+ dateNames[d.key.getMonth()] + ' '+ d.key.getFullYear() + ': ' + d.value; })
         .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
         .renderArea(true)
         .renderDataPoints(true)
         .clipPadding(data.length)
         .legend(dc.legend().y(390).x(90).itemHeight(10).itemWidth(140).gap(5).horizontal(true))
         .xUnits(d3.timeMonths)
         .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
         subscriptionChart.xAxis()
         .ticks(12)
         .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b'))


         subscriptionChart.yAxis().ticks(6);

         subscriptionChart.render();
```

The above data render chart with no data like this:[image: Currently rendered chart]

Please help me to fix this. Thank you.

**UPDATES**

**Found the solution** it was silly mistake .clipPadding(data.length) should be .clipPadding(transformedSubscriptionData.length). Updating the fiddle below.

[Solved Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4osdbjx3/)

Comment: Hi, it [renders for me](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/x924o0r8/7/) - could you fork the fiddle and add whatever is missing from the code you've posted here? And also edit the question so that others can follow what you are trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: @Gordon I have added the JSFiddle above and here is link https://jsfiddle.net/pq8z14ax/1/

Comment: @Gordon Got it. The problem was in clipPadding. Updated the fiddle. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Oh yeah I took that out because it didn't make sense to me. The [clipPadding](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.coordinateGridMixin.html#clipPadding) changes how much of the plot is visible and it is specified in pixels. So I'm not sure why you'd want to change it based on the number of items displaying. But I'm glad you got it working!